# manage.py runserver not working Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on windows and trying to learn Django. I have already made my Django project and when I go with the command prompt to the directory which has the manage.py file and type

```
manage.py runserver
```

it only opens the file manage.py. In fact I can type anything after manage.py and it will do no difference. about 20 minutes ago this same code was working properly and the server was running fine.

I have seen another thread with the same problem and the solution was simply to use

```
 `python mange.py runserver
```

however when I try that it simply says

> python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I'd appreciate any help on running my Django server.

Comment: Is `python.exe` on your PATH?

Comment: nope apparently it isn't. I opened the Enviroment Variables thing ready to add python but I don't know which address to do. should I just add C:\Python34 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not part of your `PATH`.  You can add the path to your python executable to your PATH variable.  If you're using virtual environments make sure to select the correct python executable

Comment: I've tried adding C:\Python34 to both the Path in user variables and Path in system variables and they both didn't work. I am sure C:\Python34 is the address to that folder. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're using a command prompt window that was started before making those changes, you'll have to close and re-open it.